# Simultaneous diagonalization of matrices by using their product

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are two simultaneously diagonalizable normal matrices, is it possible to find the common unitary matrix $U$ formed by their common eigenvectors by diagonalizing their product $AB$ since it is also diagonalizable by the same unitary matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're talking about normal matrices, otherwise there's no reason for $U$ to be unitary.

It will be possible if $AB$ has distinct eigenvalues.  On the other hand, you might have e.g. $AB = I$.

Comment: Why do the eigenvalues have to be distinct?

Comment: If they are not, you have lots of ways to diagonalize the matrix $AB$ which might not diagonalize $A$ or $B$.  A worst case scenario is  $AB = I$: then **any** invertible matrix $U$ can be used to diagonalize it.